# Python to update MS Excel range of cells without loop using pywin32

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

In Python (new to Python also :-)) I am trying to use pywin32 to manipulate MS Excel files. I am trying to do a handful of things that currently only pywin32 can do and other things loads of libraries can do but ideally I want to everything with just pywin32. I have been able to do everything I need except one thing (grr)! I am not able to populate a range of cells from a pandas dataframe or numpy array.  I can do this fine with VBA, example code below:

```
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Dim arr(1 To 11, 1 To 1) As Variant
Dim rex As Variant
    
For rex = -10 To 10 Step 2
    arr(i, 1) = rex
    i = i + 1
Next rex
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(15).Value = arr
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(15, 2)).Value = arr
    
Dim myArray() As Variant
myArray = '[{1; 3; 4; 2; 5; 7; 6; 8; 9; 0}]'
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Resize(15).Value = myArray
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(15, 5)).Value = myArray
```

Using Python and pywin32 I can update a range but only getting the first value in the array populating across the whole range rather than all the values in the array. Abridged version of my Python code as below:

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
import numpy as np
import psutil
import win32com
from win32com.client import VARIANT
import pythoncom

win32c = win32.constants
xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51
folderOrFilePath = sys.argv[1]

# Split fullpath, filename, base filename and extension from argument
fullPath, fileName = os.path.split(folderOrFilePath)
fileNameBase, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(fileName)

# set excel object
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
# excel can be visible or not
excel.Visible = True # Should be False for normal running / True for debugging
excel.ScreenUpdating = True # Turn off (false) for performance reasons
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.EnableEvents = False

xlWb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fullFileNamePath)

ws_obj = xlWb.Sheets('sheet1')
last_row = ws_obj.UsedRange.Rows.Count
last_col = ws_obj.UsedRange.Columns.Count
ws_content_temp = ws_obj.Range(ws_obj.Cells(1, 1), ws_obj.Cells(last_row, last_col))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ws_content_temp.Value)
dcc = df1.iloc[0].tolist()
dcc = [x.lower() for x in dcc]

df1.columns = df1.iloc[0] # Make first row the df1 column names
df1 = df1.iloc[1:] # Remove first row from the df1 as now column names

#tried defining the contents differently until I can get it working
#win32Array = ws_obj.Range(n2a(dcc.index('x')+1) + "1:" + n2a(dcc.index('x')+1) + str(lastRow)).GetValue()

#tried to populate the array manually until I can get it working
#win32Array = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_R8, [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 0])
#tried to populate the array manually until I can get it working
#win32Array = VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_VARIANT,
#        [VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 3), VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 1), VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 4),
#            VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 2), VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 5), VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 7),
#            VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 6), VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 8), VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 9),
#            VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_UI4, 0)])

#tried
#ws_obj.Cells(2, dcc.index('x')+2).Resize(df1.shape[0]).Value = df1['x'].to_numpy()
#ws_obj.Range(ws_obj.Cells(2, dcc.index('x')+2), ws_obj.Cells(df1.shape[0],dcc.index('x')+2)).Value = df1['x'].to_numpy()
#ws_obj.Cells(2, dcc.index('x')+2).Resize(df1.shape[0]).Value = win32Array
#ws_obj.Range(ws_obj.Cells(2, dcc.index('x')+2), ws_obj.Cells(df1.shape[0],dcc.index('x')+2)).Value = win32Array

xlWb.SaveAs(os.path.normpath(f'{fullPath}\\{fileNameBase}_Output.xlsx'), xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
xlWb.Close(False)
excel.ScreenUpdating = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = True
excel.EnableEvents = True
```

As I am able to update the range, but not able to get all the values in the array/dataframe distributed properly across the range I have focused my searching/attempts on trying to ensure the array/dataframe is properly defined so looked at links like https://programtalk.com/python-examples/win32com.client.VARIANT/ and http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/variant.html to highlight just two, but still so far no luck.

Looking forward to seeing what suggestions you might make.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.  The issue was apparently caused because I was selecting a single column and therefore producing a one-dimensional array when the pywin32 range object was expecting a two-dimensional array.  Working abridged code below...

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
import numpy as np
import psutil
import win32com
from win32com.client import VARIANT
import pythoncom

win32c = win32.constants
xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51
folderOrFilePath = sys.argv[1]

# Split fullpath, filename, base filename and extension from argument
fullPath, fileName = os.path.split(folderOrFilePath)
fileNameBase, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(fileName)

# set excel object
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
# excel can be visible or not
excel.Visible = True # Should be False for normal running / True for debugging
excel.ScreenUpdating = True # Turn off (false) for performance reasons
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.EnableEvents = False

xlWb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fullFileNamePath)

ws_obj = xlWb.Sheets('sheet1')
last_row = ws_obj.UsedRange.Rows.Count
last_col = ws_obj.UsedRange.Columns.Count
ws_content_temp = ws_obj.Range(ws_obj.Cells(1, 1), ws_obj.Cells(last_row, last_col))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ws_content_temp.Value)
dcc = df1.iloc[0].tolist()
dcc = [x.lower() for x in dcc]

df1.columns = df1.iloc[0] # Make first row the df1 column names
df1 = df1.iloc[1:] # Remove first row from the df1 as now column names

dataArray = pd.DataFrame(df1['x'].apply(pd.Series)).to_numpy() # Need to ensure not output a 1D Array as the Excel Range Object is expecting a 2D Array
ws_obj.Range(ws_obj.Cells(2, dcc.index('x')+1),ws_obj.Cells(df1.shape[0]+1,dcc.index('x')+1)).Value = dataArray

xlWb.SaveAs(os.path.normpath(f'{fullPath}\\{fileNameBase}_Output.xlsx'), xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
xlWb.Close(False)
excel.ScreenUpdating = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = True
excel.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that the .Resize function in pywin32 did not work the same as it does in VBA.  Was only ever able to get this to update a single cell, hence going for the .Range object method.